# Geb Testing - project folder structure contains lot of files ending as closure.class

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, geb

I am new to geb testing. We have two project folders. One of them is a subset of others. During last few days, whenever I check the status of the subset project folder using git shell, lot of closure.class files are showing as changed. But I am changing only the groovy files. I am not sure why this is happening? previously I haven't seen anything like this. 
Also lot of class files are showing as untracked files.

The file name look like this.
xxx$_$spock_feature_7_29_closure6.class

We are using IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add a .gitignore for the build output directory. It's normal that multiple class files are generated per Groovy source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of files, I mean class files generated when you try to build using gradlew. As Peter had suggested already, create a .gitignore file and add anything you want to ignore, for instance:

```
*.log
build
.gradle
.DS_Store
*.ipr
*.iml
*.iws
out
*.pem
gradle.properties
```

and run the `gradlew clean` command. You will not see those anymore. Cheers!